# Regex negative matching with python

Tags: python, regex, regex-negation

I have a string which is allowed to contain only alphabets, numbers, empty spaces and symbol ':'. So I wrote the following code :

```
regex = r'![a-zA-Z0-9\:\ ]+'
print re.match(regex, myString)
```

However it does not seem to work. I tried different combinations `r'?!([a-zA-Z0-9\:\ ])+'` and also with re.search, but it does not seem to work. Any help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want a positive match (valid characters), then use:

```
r'^[a-zA-Z0-9: ]+$'
```

If you want a negative match (whether the string has invalid characters), then:

```
r'[^a-zA-Z0-9: ]+'
```

Comment: For the first expression to work, you need to add anchors like so: `r'^[a-zA-Z0-9: ]+$'`. The second expression should work fine as-is.

Comment: I am using negative matching. Its not not working, for both[valid and invalid] strings it re.match is returning None

Comment: It must be a Python thing. According to the documentation, `match` matches "zero or more characters at the beginning of string". Try `search` instead of `match`, so `print re.search(regex, myString)`. See documentation: http://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html

Comment: +1 and accepted. Worked with search, but I was doing a mistake. I was reading file line by line and I forgot to consider newline character. Now it is working. Thank you!